Can communication be endless in graphs?
Consider the following directed network graph:

In the above graph, suppose node 1 wants to pass a message to all nodes in the network. To me, it is very logical that node 1 will simply pass the message to nodes (2,3,4) and nods (2,3,4) will pass the message. It seems to me that passing the message to all nodes will take a finite amount of time without any redundancy (i.e. no node will receive the message twice).
Now, consider the following undirected network:

I have defined a communication process in which the red node starts communicating with its neighbors, and the neighbors start communicating with their neighbors, etc.  based off the following process:
$$
S_j^{new} = S_j^{old} + \alpha \cdot \left(\frac{1}{|N_j|} \sum_{k \in N_j} (S_k - S_j^{old})\right) + \beta \cdot (S_i - S_j^{old}) + \epsilon
$$
$$
S_j^{final} = \max(0.01, \min(0.99, S_j^{new}))
$$
Where:

$S_j^{new}$ is the new score of node $j$ after the interaction
$S_j^{old}$ is the old score of node $j$ before the interaction
$S_i$ is the score of node $i$ (the specific neighbor we're considering)
$N_j$ is the set of all neighbors of node $j$ (including $i$)
$|N_j|$ is the number of neighbors of node $j$
$S_k$ is the score of each neighbor $k$ of node $j$
$\alpha$ is a weight factor for the influence of all neighbors (0 ≤ α ≤ 1)
$β$ is an additional weight factor for the influence of the specific neighbor $i$ (0 ≤ β ≤ 1)
$\epsilon$ is a random noise term, where $\epsilon \sim N(0, 0.01)$ (normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 0.01)

My Question: If this communication process continues infinitely, can we expect the score of each all nodes to eventually stabilize within some threshold $ \pm$ $c$ ? Or is there no such guarantee? What if we remove the random part - does this change anything?
How can we even begin and try to analyze such problems?

What is the difference between $i$ and $j$?

As a matter of communication, you should treat an equation in the same way as a quote or a diagram. You shouldn't simply present it with no comment, but say what it means.
Here, I think you mean for the nodes to try to communicate some value and for the scores to be estimates of that value. Each interaction appears to be between node $j$ and... all of its neighbors, but primarily $i$? in which the node replaces its old estimate by a weighted average of its old estimate, the average of its neighbors' estimates, and specifically $i$'s estimate, but each interaction adds a bit of error.

It might be clearer to write the equation in the following, equivalent, form: $$S_j^{\text{new}} = (1-\alpha-\beta)S_j^{\text{old}} + \alpha \overline{S} + \beta S_i + \varepsilon$$ where $\overline S$ is the average score of all neighbors of $j$. It makes me wonder whether you assume $\alpha + \beta \le 1$, making this a true weighted average, or where you allow for the case where $1-\alpha-\beta<0$, and the new estimate is actively trying to move away from the old estimate.

@ Misha: thank you for your feedback and recommendations ... I really appreciate it ... I am currently going over different ideas in my head and trying to settle on something logical...
